# Pandas change a categorical column that references a numerical column into several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine a data frame with 3 columns, two numerical and one categorical.

'a' and 'b' are numerical, and 'c' is categorical.

The 'c' has only two categories, and I want to convert the a and b columns into 4 columns, so I have category_1_a, category_2_a, category_1_b, category_2_b

so going from:

```
col_a.  col_b.     c.
2.       4.     cat1
3.       5.     cat2


to:

cat_1_col_a cat_1_col_b cat_2_col_a cat_2_col_b 
2.                4          na           na
na                na         3             5
```

Comment: The dataframe has many more columns than this, but these are the only ones I want to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select columns by list for subset, thn use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` for add column `c` to `index`, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting by second level and last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
#columns for processing
cols = ['col_a','col_b', 'c']
df1 = df[cols].set_index('c', append=True).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
print (df1)
   cat1_col_a  cat1_col_b  cat2_col_a  cat2_col_b
0         2.0         4.0         NaN         NaN
1         NaN         NaN         3.0         5.0
```

Last if need append DataFrame to original with remove columns by list use:

```
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1).join(df1)
```

If need first columns from new `DataFrame`:

```
df = df1.join(df.drop(cols, axis=1))
```

Comment: please see comment i've added

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
new_df = df[['col_a.','col_b.', 'c.']].set_index('c.', append=True).unstack()

# rename columns
new_df.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in new_df.columns]

# rearrange columns
new_df =  new_df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   cat1_col_a.  cat1_col_b.  cat2_col_a.  cat2_col_b.
0          2.0          4.0          NaN          NaN
1          NaN          NaN          3.0          5.0
```

Comment: The dataframe has many more columns than this, but these are the only ones I want to change. Will this still work ?